# Can I create a "button" in excel that would bring up the filter menu for a column that the "button" isn't in?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm making a reference guide in excel that has a broad audience and needs to look generally polished and non-technical. Because of this, my idea for implementing sorting and filtering was to hide the raw data way off to the right (the equivalent of one row of raw data is usually multiple rows when "prettified," so in those cases I have duplicated the same line of data the appropriate number of times) and then allow users to filter based on this data via buttons at the top of the document. However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this.

Is there any formula or macro that would turn a cell into a button that brings up the filter menu for a column that the cell itself is not in?

Any help would be immensely appreciated. I've been picking at this for hours and haven't made any progress.

Comment: (1) I’m somewhat confused about what you want to do.  Can you explain it more clearly? (2) I’m confused about where you are in the process.  You say “I have duplicated … and then allow users to …”, but then you say that you don’t know how to do … what? (3) Whatever it is that you’re trying to do, can you do it manually?  If so, have you tried recording it? … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: It's simple select the Data Range and from the `DATA Tab`, click `Filter`,, this can be done using `MACRO` also ,, just confirm through comments !!

Comment: If you're looking for a solution using VBA, its better to ask the question in StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/